# I want to make a discord-webhook but getting this error all the time

Tags: python, discord

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/kova/Desktop/Discord.py", line 35, in 
response = webhook.execute()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord_webhook/webhook.py", line 408, in execute
response = self.api_post_request(url)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord_webhook/webhook.py", line 374, in api_post_request
response = requests.post(
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 117, in post
return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 515, in request
prep = self.prepare_request(req)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 443, in prepare_request
p.prepare(
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 321, in prepare
self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 473, in prepare_body
body = complexjson.dumps(json, allow_nan=False)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/json/**init**.py", line 238, in dumps
**kw).encode(obj)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
return _iterencode(o, 0)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.**class**.**name**} '
TypeError: Object of type Tag is not JSON serializable

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code.

Answer (score 0):

The actual error you get is `TypeError: Object of type Tag is not JSON serializable`
Now, it is really hard to help you with this issue without a proper formatted traceback and without the code. The Error means, that the stuff you got as response from the API isn't json. As i said above already, I indeed can give you good help after you included the code and format the Code & Traceback correctly.